# Render custom layout instead of application layout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

When an error occurs during create process, render new action is invoked. I need to display the custom layout for new. Instead it is displaying the application layout. How to fix the issue?

```
def new
  @user = User.new
  render layout: 'theme_forest'
end

def create
  @user = User.new(user_params)

  respond_to do |format|
  if @user.save
    @user.add_role(COMPANY_ADMIN)
    sign_in @user
    format.html { redirect_to "/users",
                  notice: 'User was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render json: @user, status: :created,
                  location: "/users" }
  else
    format.html { render :new }
    format.json { render json: @user.errors, status:  :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
```

end

Comment: `render layout: 'theme_forest'` in new action is correct. do you get any errors ?

Comment: Try changing this `format.html { render :new }` to `format.html { render :new, layout: 'theme_forest'}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mentioned, you should change

```
format.html { render :new }
```

to

```
format.html { render :new, layout: 'theme_forest'}
```

> When an error occurs during create process, render new action is
>   invoked

**Explanation:**

No! When you use `render`, it just **loads the template**(i.e, `new.html.erb`). It **won't invoke/trigger** the corresponding `controller#method`(i.e, `new`). So `render layout: 'theme_forest'` in the `new` method **never gets called** in this situation.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you have is that you are not telling the renderer to use your custom layout.

In the new action you have correctly added `render layout: 'theme_forest'`,
however you have not done the same in your create action.

in your create action, in the else block

```
format.html { render :new }
format.json { render json: @user.errors, status:  :unprocessable_entity }
```

the `render :new` command does not invoke your new action, it only renders the new.html.erb template, you therefore need to add the layout option to the render method as pavan's comment suggests if you want to use a different layout:

```
format.html { render :new, layout: 'theme_forest' }
format.json { render json: @user.errors, status:  :unprocessable_entity }
```